# How to activate the deep link from the iPhone Gmail App to my custom iPhone App?

Tags: ios, email, gmail, deep-linking

I am unable to open my custom iPhone App from the link in the email that I get from a Gmail App. On the other hand, the link is correctly navigating me to my iPhone custom app from the Mail App.

The issue is only from the gmail app.

Below is the code that gets triggered.

```
<a style="font-family: Helvetica;
          height: 30px;
          font-size: 20px;
          text-decoration: none;
          line-height: 1.5;
          letter-spacing: 0.5px;
          text-align: center;
          color: #ffffff;"
          href="app_name://action/open/page/home">
    View App
</a>
```

Kindly let me know the solution. I have been searching about this from a long time. Appreciate in advance.

Comment: Did you considered using Universal Links instead of Custom URL scheme? Custom URL scheme does not have nice to handle case where App is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this problem before when trying to do deeplinking from gmail app and realize that gmail app wont allow the link to be opened directly

My workaround for this is instead of inject app direct deeplink inside the email, we add our server url there, when user click that link and request send to that server url we do a redirect to app's deeplink and that works.